# Difference of seminorms

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

Given a Hilbert space $H$, take a continuous functional $f\in X^*$ and define a map $\|\cdot\|':H\to\mathbb R$ by $\|y\|^\prime = \|y\| - |f(y)|$. Can it happen that this is a Hilbert-space norm when $f$ is non-zero?

Comment: Every continuous functional $f$ is of the form $f(y) =\langle x, y\rangle $ for some $x\in H$.

Comment: Thus, given $x\not=0$,  we have $ \Vert x\Vert'=0$. Therefore $\Vert.\Vert$ is not a Norm.

Comment: Well, it gives $\Vert x\Vert-\Vert x\Vert^2$.

Comment: Correction: One has to define $f$ by $f(y):=\Vert x\Vert^{-1}\langle x, y\rangle$.

Comment: Please don't delete a post shortly after getting an answer. That deprives the answerer a chance to get some community appreciation. If you are unhappy with your question you should EDIT it.

Comment: @JensSchwaiger:  you can only do that if $\|f\|=1$.

Comment: That's the *2nd* [tag:functional-analysis] problem being recently [self-deleted](//math.stackexchange.com/q/2766689/290189).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that $\|\cdot\|'$ is not a norm, but here is an easy way to at least show that it is not a Hilbert norm.

For better notation, let me write $\|y\|_0=\|y\|-|f(y)|$.

Let $z_0\in (\ker f)^\perp$ with $f(z_0)=1$. Then $H=\ker f+\mathbb C z_0$. So any $x\in H$ is of the form $x=x_0+\lambda z_0$, with $x_0\in\ker f$. Note that $\|x_0\|_0=\|x_0\|$. We have, using the Parallelogram Law,
$$\tag1
\|x_0+\lambda z_0\|_0^2+\|x_0-\lambda z_0\|_0^2=2\|x_0\|_0^2+2|\lambda|^2\,\|z_0\|_0^2=2\|x_0\|^2+2|\lambda|^2(\|z_0\|-1)^2
$$
On the other hand, by definition, 
\begin{align}\tag2
\|x_0+\lambda z_0\|_0^2+\|x_0-\lambda z_0\|_0^2
&=(\|x_0+\lambda z_0\|-|\lambda|)^2+(\|x_0-\lambda z_0\|-|\lambda|)^2\\ \ \\
&=\|x_0+\lambda z_0\|^2+\|x_0-\lambda z_0\|^2+2|\lambda|^2-2|\lambda|(\|x_0+\lambda z_0\|+\|x_0-\lambda z_0\|)\\ \ \\
&=2\|x_0\|^2+2|\lambda|^2\,\|z_0\|^2+2|\lambda|^2-2|\lambda|(\|x_0+\lambda z_0\|+\|x_0-\lambda z_0\|).
\end{align}
Comparing $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get 
$$\tag3
4|\lambda|^2\|z_0\|=2|\lambda|(\|x_0+\lambda z_0\|+\|x_0-\lambda z_0\|).
$$
The equality $(3)$ will hold for any $\lambda$. First, for any nonzero $\lambda$ we get 
$$\tag4
2|\lambda|\|z_0\|=\|x_0+\lambda z_0\|+\|x_0-\lambda z_0\|.
$$
Now making $\lambda\to0$ we obtain $2\|x_0\|=0$, a contradiction since the above should work for any $x_0$.  Or, we can see the above as a proof that $\ker f=0$, so $H=\mathbb C$.

In this latter case, when $\dim H=1$, the norm $\|\cdot\|_0$ is a norm, provided that $\|f\|< 1$.